# Get number of occurrences/times between two dates

Tags: php, date, datetime, time, calendar

I'm trying to get the number of times between two dates. I'm provided with 4 types of info: `freq`, `interval`, `startDate`, and `endDate`.

For example:

```
freq = weekly
interval = 1
startDate = 2019-03-10
endDate = 2019-03-24
```

I'm trying to get the number of times/dates/events are between those two dates with the given info. (The **count** or the number of events)

In this example, since the frequency is `weekly` and the interval is 1, it means repeat the event on the startDate every 1 week. If the interval was changed to 2, it would be every 2 weeks. If the frequency was changed to daily, and the interval was 3, it would be every 3 days.

In this example, the first event would be on `2019-03-10` and then the second event would be on `2019-03-17`, and then the third would be on `2019-03-24`. The **`count`** is 3 in this example because there are three dates.

I am trying to find the **count**.

Thanks

Comment: Please share your attempts. Also please list the possible frequencies.

Comment: Question. In your example 'freq' and 'interval' are divisible by the 'startDate' and 'endDate', but if you just changed 'interval' from '1' to '3', 'startDate' and 'endDate' would no longer be divisible by 'freq' and 'interval'. Example... interval 1, weekly, equals 2019-03-10 (1), 2019-03-17 (2), 2019-03-24 (3), but interval 3, weekly would just equal 2019-03-10 (1) because the next interval would be 2019-03-31 which is past the 'endDate' 2019-03-24. So my (?) is...so does the 'endDate' guarantee that an 'event' will happen on the 'endDate' even if the 'NEXT INTERVAL' is past the 'endDate'...

Comment: ... and if that is true the count for 'interval' 3, weekly would equal 2019-03-10 (1), 2019-03-24 (2), or if that's not true, 'interval' 3, weekly would just equal 2019-03-10 (1)... so which rule would it follow... return (1) or return (2) when interval = 3, freq = weekly, and statrDate = 2019-03-10, and endDate = 2019-03-24?

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you use Datetime class or Carbon, you can easily loop through the days/weeks/months between those dates. For example, if your freq = weekly and interval = 1, given the startDate and endDate you provided, the code would be something like this:

```php
use Carbon\Carbon;

$startDate = Carbon::create(2019,03,10,0,0);

$endDate =  Carbon::create(2019,03,24,0,0);

$count = 0;

while(! $startDate->greaterThan($endDate) ) 
{
     $count += 1;

     if($freq === 'weekly')
     {
        $startDate->addWeeks($interval);
     }
     else if($freq === 'monthly') 
     {
        $stardDate->addMonths($interval);
     }
}
```

In this example i've made using carbon because it saves you a lot of time, but you could do this by using PHP Datetime Class.